# .equals acting really funny

Tags: java

```
         for (int y = 0; y < stuff.length(); y++)
        {
            String n = wordTemp[y];
            String m = complete [y];
            System.out.println(n + m);
            if (n.equals(m));
            {
                fin = fin + 1;
            }
        }

        if (fin == stuff.length())
        {
            System.out.println("COMPLETED!  Play again later.");
            return;
        }
```

This is the last part of my hangman main method.  I currently have two arrays running.  The first being complete[], which contains an inputted word chopped into character-by-character substring.  The second array I have is the "guessed" word array. 
e.g. if the word is fish, complete[] would contain [f,i,s,h} while wordTemp would contain [f,-,-,-] if I JUST guessed f.

However, when I go to compare the elements of these two arrays to see if the user has completed the challenge, I jump right out of java.  Here's how it ends up going:

After taking a first guess, the whole thing skips out.  I suspect that the .equals isn't working, but what can I do to replace it?

Answer (score 9):

```
 if (n.equals(m));
```

should be

```
 if (n.equals(m))
```

Delete the semicolon.

This is part of the reason auto-formatting IDEs are nice, and personally, it's, part of the reason I like Egyptian-style brackets -- `if (n.equals(m)) {` with the open bracket on the same line.  Little things like that make syntax issues like extra semicolons more obvious.

Comment: +1. Egyptian style brackets are always helpful to avoid syntax errors.